# A search path is not honored in macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave)

Tags: path, zsh, homebrew, macos-mojave

I am running macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave, 18G87)

My default shell is Zsh and $`PATH` is set in `.zshrc` as follows;

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin:/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I use Homebrew to manage packages and as you can see brewed gcc and `llvm` is a front of `/usr/bin` where Apple's gcc is. However, for some reasons I don't understand, Mojave sees Appple's gcc in `/usr/bi`,

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I'd really appreciate  any pointers to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was pretty simple to fix.  The latest brewed gcc is gcc-9 and all I had to do was to `ln -s gcc-9, gcc`.  This fixed the issue.